# How many ways can the word “individual” be arranged that contains the word ‘dual’? Is it $(6!/(1!*1!*1!*2!*1!)) * 7$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

How many ways can the word “individual” be arranged that contains the word ‘dual’?

Here’s how I am attempting to solve:
10!-4! from the used letters of dual = 6!/(1!*1!*1!*2!*1!)

Then multiply by 7 for the possible places the word dual could fit among the other letters including beginning and end.

(6!/(1!*1!*1!*2!*1!)) * 7

Is this how a problem like this is solved?

Comment: **i**nd**i**v**i**dual has three letters `i` in it.  Where do you account for that in your attempt?

Comment: The answer is the same as the number of arrangements of "indivix".  Then replace "x" by "dual".

Comment: As an aside... when talking about how many remaining letters there are outside of the letters used for `dual`... write that as $10-4$.  There is no reason to have written $10!-4!$.  The expression $10!-4!$ has nothing to do with this problem.  Don't just throw exclamation marks where they don't belong.

Answer (score 1):

We can mix 3×`i`, `n`, `d`, `v` and `dual` which makes $7! / 3!$ arrangements, because it's 7 strings and the 3 `i`'s can be arranged in 3! ways each time.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

Permute INDIVI in $\;\dfrac{6!}{3!}$ ways,

and insert $\boxed{DUAL}$ at any of the uparrows $\uparrow I \uparrow N \uparrow D \uparrow  
I \uparrow V \uparrow I \uparrow$